# Is there any disadvantage of using thread safe collection classes like Hashtable in single thread environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, hashtable

I was asked by the interviewer about disadvantages of using thread safe class like Hashtable in single threaded environment? Are there any disadvantages? if not then why are there non thread safe class introduced later?

Comment: There is a minor performance penalty due to the methods being `synchronized`, but in most cases it won't be measurable.

Comment: @Lino 'They probably need more memory' why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was asked by the interviewer about disadvantages of using thread safe class like Hashtable in single threaded environment?

There are, although most of the disadvantages are around performance.  Even single-threaded environments have multiple threads in them (think GC, finalizers, signal handlers, JMX, etc.) so the language still needs to obey the synchronization constructs such as `synchronized`, `volatile`, and the native lock implementations.  These language features flush or invalidate memory caches and affect code reordering both of which can dramatically affect overall runtime performance.

> if not then why are there non thread safe class introduced later?

Non-thread-safe objects always perform better than their thread-safe counterparts in either single or multi-threaded applications.  The ability to deal with local CPU cached memory is one of the main speed increases provided by modern hardware.  If you don't have to reach out to the main memory bus, you can execute operations orders of magnitude faster.  Synchronization constructs decrease the ability of cache memory to be used.

Lastly, thread-safe classes are typically more complicated both in terms of the data structures involved as well as the logic necessary for them to operate correctly in a multi-thread application.  This means that even if we ignore the synchronization constructures, it may use more memory and run slower, although the degree to which this is the case is very dependent on the particular class in question

Answer (score 1):

1. They are slower in single thread environment. Modern JIT is very effective in working with synchronized class in single thread environment, but it is not perfect.
2. They are much slower in multi thread environment. In case you have immutable collection you can safely use from different threads, but synchronized collection will work much slower.
3. [design] Its locking semantic is mostly useless, so additional synchronization needed anyway. You rarely need just read or write, most of time you read then write and you want it to be atomic. Or you want to allow multiple simultaneous reads.

Comment: The thread safe collections from 1.0 were made generic in 1.5 (like they did with the collection framework), so I have to disagree with your first argument.

Comment: [`java.util.Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is generic, and that's the only class actually mentioned in the question. What classes are you talking about that aren't?

Comment: OK Now quantify 'much slower in multi-threaded environment'. And don't just strike out your mistakes here. Remove them. They have no permanent value whatsoever.

Comment: I don't have numbers at hand, but it is obvious that synchronization doesn't come for free. In case of single thread runtime use thread pinning which basically skips most of checks in case instance used only in one thread, but if multiple threads access it runtime must do proper locking.